# PHP : How to change OCI(oracle) upload file to postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql, oracle, php-pgsql

I need help regarding migrating my OCI upload file to postgresql file. I've tried multiple ways from Youtube. I am new to pgsql and really in a pinch right now. Need help. Thank you!.

Here is the code:

```
$file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); //get index.php
if ($file!='index.php') include_once "nologin.php";
   
   
$result = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']) && $_FILES['myfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
    $no_kp_baru   = $_POST['no_kp_baru'];
    $latihan_id = $_POST['latihan_id'];
    $tkh_mula1 = $_POST['tkh_mula'];
    $masa_mula = $_POST['masa_mula'];
    
    list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $tkh_mula1);//'dd/mm/yyyy' format
    $mk=mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
    $tkh_mula=strftime('%d-%b-%Y',$mk);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    include_once "../db_conn.php";
    
    $sql = "
    update log_latihan set
        PENGESAHAN = NULL,
        TKH_PENGESAHAN = NULL,
        ID_PENGESAH = NULL
    where
        NO_KP_BARU = :NO_KP_BARU
        and LATIHAN_ID = :LATIHAN_ID
        and TKH_MULA = :TKH_MULA
        and MASA_MULA = :MASA_MULA
        ";
    
    // Update using bind variables
    $parse = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    oci_bind_by_name($parse, ":NO_KP_BARU", $no_kp_baru);
    oci_bind_by_name($parse, ":LATIHAN_ID", $latihan_id);
    oci_bind_by_name($parse, ":TKH_MULA", $tkh_mula);
    oci_bind_by_name($parse, ":MASA_MULA", $masa_mula);
    oci_execute($parse);
    //echo oci_num_rows($parse);
    if (oci_num_rows($parse))
    {
    
        $stmt = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO log_latihan_sijil (no_kp_baru,latihan_id,tkh_mula,masa_mula,nama_fail,type,saiz_fail,tkh_upload,sijil) 
        VALUES(:NO_KP_BARU,:LATIHAN_ID,to_date(:TKH_MULA,'DD/MM/YYYY'),:MASA_MULA,:NAMA_FAIL,:TYPE,:SAIZ_FAIL,sysdate,EMPTY_BLOB()) RETURNING sijil INTO :FILE_CONTENT");
        
        $lob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':FILE_CONTENT', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":NO_KP_BARU", $no_kp_baru);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":LATIHAN_ID", $latihan_id);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":TKH_MULA", $tkh_mula1);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":MASA_MULA", $masa_mula);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":NAMA_FAIL", $fileName);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":TYPE", $fileType);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":SAIZ_FAIL", $fileSize);
        oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
        //var_dump(oci_error($stmt));

        if ($lob->savefile($tmpName)) {
            oci_commit($conn);
            $result=1;
        }
        $lob->free();
        oci_free_statement($stmt);
    }
    oci_free_statement($parse);
}
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Theres not an error.It just doesn't work.I need to migrate the codes to postgresql and having a big problem.
it will work on Oracle of course. Just need to replace it with postgreSQL.I've spent hours trying to find the solution but cant seem to find it

Comment: Take a look at [Migrate your mindset too](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/). While its examples are from MS SQL Server the lesson is the same ***You need to understand what the old code does in order to rewrite to the new system***. You cannot expect to just dump code from one database to another. Particular here as OCL is Oracle proprietary software (Oracle Call Interface). There is NO direct replacement in Postgres.

Comment: What is your question? 
You should read You Should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask good question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.